# Compile old kernel with new gcc

Tags: linux-kernel, gcc

I'm trying to compile an older version of Linux (3.4) on my Linux box with its current gcc-6.3. But running the make command shows errors like this:

```
scripts/kconfig/conf.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

And I haven't found any solution yet. It seems that the gcc requires using fPIC flag for some objects which the 3.4 kernel config files haven't asked so. Preferably I don't want to touch the kernel defaults. How should I ask the gcc to stop requiring this flag or to disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever error I solved a new one appeared in next compilation try. Unfortunately the best solution I found was to use an older gcc to compile this kernel.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are using a version of gcc that is modified to produce PIE (position independent executables) by default. According to this [page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE) at least Ubuntu has done this switch. The code in the `scripts/kconfig` directory is for auxiliary programs that is not linked into the kernel, and (afaik) does not link to external static libraries. Thus it shouldn't really matter what the default is, **unless** you have some leftovers from a previous run with a compiler version with a different default. Run `make clean` and recompile.

If this does not help, take a look at the [Makefile](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/Makefile#L628) for the current kernel, which forces `-no-pie`.

Comment: Thanks I did a `make clean` and the previous error disappeared but a new one is now shown: `scripts/mod/empty.c:1:0:  error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode`. Also a warning says: `arch/x86/Makefile:81: stack protector enabled but no compiler support`

Comment: You will have to copy the `-fno-pie` setting from the current Makefile to tell your compiler to not produce position independent code. Or, you will have to get (build) a compiler which does not generate PIC by default. Editing the Makefile is probably easier. I guess you can ignore the stack protector warning.

Comment: I edited the Makefile and the previous error gave way to another new one: `include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:100:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc6.h: No such file or directory`. I looked at the include directory of this kernel and it only has header files for gcc3 and gcc4. It seems that I have to use an older gcc to compile this. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's beginning to look like using an older compiler is the safest and easiest way.